# Can multiple 100k Lasso Regressions on the same dataset be parallelized in Python?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, parallel-processing, regression

Hi I am currently facing an issue when trying to run a large number of Lasso Regressions on the same data.
I have a dataset with multiple 100k rows and 365 columns (data of one year).
What I need to do is to fit and predict one Lasso Regression per Row based on all other rows so that I end up with as many individual regressions as rows.

I struggle to find a way other than a loop to execute this in a rather performant way. I tried to experiment with Python's joblib package, which increased the performance, but I am still looking for a faster way if there is any. I also tried to find a way to vectorize this problem, but I did not find a solution. I also glanced at keras to implement the Lasso regression as an aNN.

I can hardly imagine that it is uncommon to fit a large number of simple models for specific tasks. So my question is: **What is the best approach to reduce execution time of this problem statement?** From my understanding, this problem can not be optimized with the use of GPUs as lots of individual models need to be fitted and therefore the CPU will be the bottleneck regardless.

Btw: I can get access to a GPU and I have a CPU with 16 cores.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is like leave-one-out crossvalidation, with 365 folds... I would recommend doing max 37 folds: 355 data for training, 10 for test. 364 vs 355 training data is small difference

Comment: @dankal444 thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, as this is not about cross-validation I need one prediction for each row. This is a fixed requirement of my problem statement.

Comment: That is understandable that you need one prediction per each row, but do you really need all available train data to make a model? Second thing, [here](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#lasso-regression)  is some gpu-accelerated lasso regression

Comment: Thanks for the link to cuML, I will look into it.
Concerning the training data: yes the idea is that all training data is used, but due to how the Lasso regulizer works, that the model itself reduces the features it actually considers. That is intended.